# converting System::String to wchar_t* - how is the end determined?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, interop

The process is explained here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/d1ae6tz5%28v=VS.80%29.aspx
What I don't get from that article is that the pinned wchar_t* is passed to various C string functions that rely on the trailing null character. Is it a rule that .NET strings have a trailing null character? The System.String docs say that:

> In the .NET Framework, a null character can be embedded in a string. When a string includes one or more null characters, they are included in the length of the total string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, the internal character buffer in .NET CLR strings is null-terminated, although naturally that null character doesn't make it into the character count, so any .NET code would ignore it. The only reason that null is there is for easy interop with Windows API or other plain C code that expects strings to be null-terminated. Instead of appending a null character any time a .NET string has to be passed to a C API (and possibly having to reallocate and copy the entire string), the null character is just there from the first place - a useful optimization in the real-world, since .NET still has to do a lot of interop behind the scenes, even if you don't use it explicitly.

If you do happen to have some null characters *in the middle* of your string, well, any C API that gets your string would probably stop there and never reach the end of the string. I guess you can even try it in C++/CLI yourself and see what happens. :)

Comment: Actually, when I retrieve wchar_t* of a System::String, I see a couple of trash characters after the end of the text and before the null character. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that the string comes from Windows.Forms.TextBox?

Comment: Maybe, though I can't really see the reason why. The text of a Windows.Forms.TextBox certainly has to go through the Windows API (which would require it to be null-terminated) somewhere, but I don't know why you'd get garbage there.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, because I don't have access to Microsoft internals.

It isn't explicitly stated, but a wchar_t* string should always be terminated with a null character. The example supports this, since it uses the `printf_s` function which depends on this characteristic.

The `PtrToStringChars` function is granting access to an internal string buffer. It is possible for the function to append a null character to the buffer without including it in the character count of the string, thus the .NET users of the string would not see the null.

Comment: PtrToStringChars() is defined in the [vcclr.h](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#ep_dW72sfTE/trunk/trunk/include/ntddk/inc/ddk/wlh/vcclr.h&q=file:vcclr.h&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) include file, so you can look at it yourself. It doesn't seem to append characters to the string buffer or modify it in any way. It just gives you the pointer to the internal character buffer.

Comment: @Boaz Yaniv, thanks for the link. I don't see any appending either. I must assume that the other String functions maintain a null at the end of the buffer without including it in the character count.

Comment: There's scarcely any information about that, but the few article I've found which discuss the issue seem to [indicate that](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx).